# Missing FileSystemDirectoryHandle.keys() method in VSCode IntelliSense

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, origin-private-file-system

I miss the `FileSystemDirectoryHandle.keys()` method in VS Code (version 1.84.1). TypeScript version 5.2.2 is used. Is there a specific reason that this method is not shown and is there a plan to include this in the lib.dom.d.ts file under FileSystemDirectoryHandle in the future?

Or do I have to set something else in the tsconfig.json? I have “ESNext” under “module” and “target”.

Answer (score 0):

Googling "`site:github.com/microsoft "FileSystemDirectoryHandle" "keys"`", I don't see any existing issue tickets about this, so <s>I'd suggest that you raise one in [the TypeScript repo](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript) or in https://github.com/microsoft/dts-gen. Issue ticket has been raised at https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/56360. Strange since (at least according to MDN), [most browsers support it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemDirectoryHandle#browser_compatibility).</s> This is now implemented by PR [Add asynciterable libs #56723](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/56723).

The closest thing I found was https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/wicg-file-system-access/index.d.ts, which is the DefinitelyTyped package for https://github.com/WICG/file-system-access, where it *is* defined. I suppose you could use that types package as a workaround in the meantime.